# Save PDF form Chrome IFRAME

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, iframe

I am POSTING a form to an IFRAME (target) which returns a PDF (content-disposition=inline;filename="x.pdf").

This works with current Chrome and Firefox and the embedded PDF viewer.

The only problem is, that Chrome is not able to save the PDF (it tries to save x.html with no content) (with Ctrl+S and with the icon in the PDF toolbar).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is a limitation from native Chrome PDF Viewer. You cannot save PDF file when it is displayed from an iframe using Chrome PDF Viewer (plugin).

Using Adobe Reader plugin for Chrome works perfectly.

Cheers

Comment: The problem is: We author the website but don't configure your (someone else's) web browser.